# Minimum grid distance for orthogonal router

Tags: jointjs

I have issue drawing links with router property set to orthogonal.

In the image attached below, I'm trying to draw a link from point A to B (horizontal line Y co-ordinate is same).
When the points are near, I want the link to be a straight line but, router takes a different orthogonal path.
Until I reach some min distance along the horizon I don't see a straight line.

[orthogonal links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqGBi.png)

So, I'm doubtful if minimum distance/ minimum grid units is set for the router (paper grid is set to 5)?

If, yes, is there a way to overcome this issue?

If, no, then is there a workaround, where I can prevent the movement of elements if distance between elements goes below the threshold distance set for orthogonal router?

Answer (score 1):

Solve it using below code snippet:

[Minimum Grid Distance for orthogonal router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc93u.png)